# See all Facebook comments I have made on blogs, articles, etc

Tags: facebook, comments

I recently noticed when posting Facebook comments on articles or blogs, that I am labelled as a *Top Commenter*. After the initial surge of pride and feelings of adequacy, I got to wonder what useful comments I have made.

But I can't find a way to list off all my comments. With Disqus, you can view your profile and get a list of all your comments made and their respective up/downvotes. Is a similar interface possible with Facebook?

Comment: Someone answered this same question here too: https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=1046414365368665

Answer (score 10):

You can access all comments from your **Activity Log**. First open your timeline view, and there's a link to access the Activity log.

[image: Screenshot: Link to access the Activity log on Facebook timeline view]

From the Activity log, select "Comments", and you'll get a chronological list of all your comments.

[image]

In addition, you can also [request a download of your Facebook data](https://www.facebook.com/help/www/131112897028467?rdrhc), if you want to do some automated analysis or processing on it. You can do this from Account settings. It takes a while for the download to be ready. "Once your download is ready, [Facebook will] send an email to the email address listed on your Facebook account along with a link to your download."

However, it's quite possible neither of these methods provide the **amount of likes on each of your comments**. The [description on types of provided data](https://www.facebook.com/help/405183566203254) does mention that

> Likes on Your Posts from others: Likes on your own posts, photos or other content

would be included in the Activity log, but I can't seem to find that anywhere. For example, a comment that has been liked:

[image] [image]

does not show those likes when displayed in the Activity log:

[image]

and neither can those like-events be found as individual items on the log. Whether that information is included in the downloaded data dump, I do not know, but would be interested in finding out.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.facebook.com/help/405183566203254

That help article describes the data available to users who request a download of their data.

Comments would appear in the Activity Log, so you may need to process the collection to filter out the non-comment entries.